# Wpcf7 Dom Events not working

Tags: wordpress, events, dom

This should be very simple but it just does not work and I have no clue why.
Can somebody please explain to me what the problem is?
I have tried my code and the documentation example and nothing works at all.
Link to docs: [Contact Form 7 Dom Events](https://contactform7.com/dom-events/)

My code:

```
$('.hollow-form-01 form.wpcf7-form').on('wpcf7submit', function() {
  alert('submitted');
});
```

Documentation Example:

```
var wpcf7Elm = document.querySelector( '.wpcf7' );

wpcf7Elm.addEventListener( 'wpcf7submit', function( event ) {
 alert( "Fire!" );
}, false );
```

Comment: Do you get error(s) in the console? In WordPress, the `$` _is not_ `jQuery` (jQuery loads in no-conflict mode).  Further, you probably need this code inside of a document ready statement.  `jQuery(function($) { ... your code inside here ... });`

Comment: Thank you for your response!

I realize I was lacking a bit of context but the issue was not related to jQuery or wordpress. There were two issues: I was targeting the wrong part of the form and the events in the documentation do not work as stated.

This is how  got it to work:

    $('.hollow-form-01 .wpcf7').on('wpcf7:mailsent', function() {
    $('.hollow-form-01 .active').removeClass('active');
    $('.hollow-form-01 .messageSuccess').addClass('active');
  });

Comment: @gumball Thanks for this Really helped!
I changed my code to `$('.wpcf7').on('wpcf7:mailsent', function() {` instead of `document.addEventListener( 'wpcf7mailsent', function( event ) {` this then worded as expected